# How to display a video in an iframe on page in Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, iframe

Hi I am trying to display an iframe video from YouTube on a page. I get a 404 error on blank block when I run the page. What could possibly be wrong?

My code is:

```
<iframe width="854" height="480" src="{{ $vid->videoURL . '&output=embed' }}" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: URL is valid, it is copied and pasted

Comment: Check your console/network tab in browser.

Comment: `Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8nbsSkwSbb0&output=embed' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`

Comment: Make your url as `https://www.youtube.com/embed/8nbsSkwSbb0`.

Comment: `{{ 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' . explode('?v=', $vid->videoURL)[1] }}`

Comment: @linktoahref - can I ask you about the array [1]? I get an undefined offset error because of it. I am not sure why you put it there, do you mind explaining, please?

Comment: Don't worry, I made another plan, it is working now

Comment: @Horcrux I tried to explode the string and get the first portion of the array, which would be the video id

Answer (score 0):

Change your `url` from `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8nbsSkwSbb0&output=embed` to `https://www.youtube.com/embed/8nbsSkwSbb0`. The  `/embed` endpoint allows outside requests, while the `/watch` does not. I think, you can create an `accessor` method in your `Video` model like this:

```
public function getSrcAttribute()
{
    // $this->videoUrl: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8nbsSkwSbb0
    parse_str(parse_url($this->videoURL)['query'], $output);
    return 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $output['v'];
}
```

Then use it like:

```
<iframe
src="{{ $vid->src }}"
width="854"
height="480"
frameborder="0"
allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"
allowfullscreen></iframe>
```